# Using logcat: a bit confused here :(

Tags: android

I'm new to using logcat and debugging in Android. I've analyzing someone else's code which looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class RestClient {



    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /* This is a test function which will connects to a given
     * rest service and prints it's response to Android Log with
     * labels "Praeda".
     */
    public static void connect(String url)
    {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Examine the response status
            Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                Log.i("Praeda",result);

                // A Simple JSONObject Creation
                JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
                Log.i("Praeda","<jsonobject>\n"+json.toString()+"\n</jsonobject>");

                // A Simple JSONObject Parsing
                JSONArray nameArray=json.names();
                JSONArray valArray=json.toJSONArray(nameArray);
                for(int i=0;i<valArray.length();i++)
                {
                    Log.i("Praeda","<jsonname"+i+">\n"+nameArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonname"+i+">\n"
                            +"<jsonvalue"+i+">\n"+valArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonvalue"+i+">");
                }

                // A Simple JSONObject Value Pushing
                json.put("sample key", "sample value");
                Log.i("Praeda","<jsonobject>\n"+json.toString()+"\n</jsonobject>");

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

How do I run this so I can watch the log? Do I need to actually have an activity which calls the function or....? I'm so confused....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this as an Android application. Click on DDMS icon at the top corner of Eclipse .  Click on LogCat in the next window. Alternatively, OPEN-> perspective (or view on the toolbar) ->Logcat .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to invoke the static method from an Activity (e.g., [Hello World](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html)). Once the Activity is running, you can monitor the Activity's log output from logcat (using [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) or [adb](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html)).

Comment: it was a mistake and it wouldnt let me reverse! you have to edit your answer somehow so I can undo. So sorry.

Comment: @helloworld, edit your answer (e.g. just add a period or something) and I can upvote, if you still care.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a new activity and have to call this static method `connect(String url)`

```
RestClient.connect("http://www.example.com");
```

Further, for the logcat output click on the `i` in LogCat View.